What is the name of this anime where a teenage boy goes through portal into another world?
The story starts off with the main character wanting his father, who is a scientist to come home and the father said he would but broke his promise. Then the boy and his best friend talk about it, then some stuff happens I think the best friend died but I could be wrong. Then the boy is visited by a stranger through a portal and is invited by the stranger to come through the portal.
The boy goes through the portal and it leads him to another world and that's almost all I can remember besides some guy that becomes the boy's mentor being mistreated by a royal.

In roughly which year did you watch this? And can you tell us more about the other world?

well the anime came out in the 2000's I believe and all I remember is that there was magic or some type of power in the other world and the mc challenged the royal to a fight I think and that's all I can remember

Did you see this on TV? And was it a series or a movie?

I didn't see it on tv but it was a series

You could improve this question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
